# Using Collectors to split steam into lists based on class in Java

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

The following code is a pseudo code that denotes what I want to achieve:

```
Map<Class<?>, List<?>> map = Stream.of(1, "2").collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Object::getClass));
List<Integer> ints = map.get(Integer.class);
List<String> strings = map.get(String.class);
```

The above is a simplified code. What I want is I have an input list, I want to split it into multiple lists based on the class of the objects.

However the code above does not compile, I wonder how can you fix it?

Comment: “the code above does not compile” that’s likely because there is a problem. Seriously, if you have error, post them, instead of saying that you have errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line can be fixed by changing `List<?>` to `List<Object>`:

```
Map<Class<?>, List<Object>> map = Stream.of(1, "2")
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Object::getClass));
```

The next lines are more problematic. I don't think there's any way to define that sort of generic relationship in Java. You'll have to use an ugly, unsafe cast:

```
List<Integer> ints = (List)map.get(Integer.class);
List<String> strings = (List)map.get(String.class);
```

If you want to make it more safe and user-friendly, you can hide it behind a custom class:

```
class TypeToListMap {
    private Map<Class<?>, List<Object>> map = ...

    public <T> List<T> get(Class<T> key) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<T> result = (List<T>)map.get(key); 
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `<T> List<T> get(Class<T>)` method is the preferable way. It does not only hide the unchecked operation; it’s combining it with the operation that should ensure the correctness, i.e. using the `Class` as lookup key. So it’s reducing the errors you can make.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `List<Object>` instead of `List<?>`:

```
Map<Class<?>, List<Object>> map = Stream.of(1, "2")
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Object::getClass));
List<Object> ints = map.get(Integer.class);
List<Object> strings = map.get(String.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the type of:

```
Stream.of(1, "2");
```

is actually:

```
Stream<?> stream = Stream.of(1, "2");
```

And the only legal substitute for `?` would be `Object` in this case.

Because of type erasure `?` would be Object.

It's like you need to declare the type of your List at runtime with generics. Its like doing this:

```
T x;
List<x.getClass()> list = ...; // can't do that
```

You can do a hack here and cast twice :)

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Integer> ints = (List<Integer>) (List<?>) map.get(Integer.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can just cast results. Lists should really consist of objects of required types so there shouldn't be a problem. You may receive a compiler warning though (if you specified to compiler that you want to receive unchecked cast warnings).

```
    Map<Class, ?> map = Stream.of(1, "2").collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Object::getClass));
    List<Integer> ints = (List<Integer>) map.get(Integer.class);
    List<String> strings = (List<String>) map.get(String.class);
```

Comment: And actually it can be, you need to use erasure: `List<Integer> = (List) ... `